# Replacing string after match

Tags: regex, string, perl, replace

I'm new to perl and was wondering how I could replace some text after a matched pattern.

For example I have a string:

```
    my $string = 'startDate="2014-06-10"';
    $string =~ s/startDate="2014-06-10"/startDate=""\g;
```

This code replaces what I want but I want to be able to have any date and for it replace the date with a blank string. So I want to replace any text after `startDate="` and stop replacing after 10 characters. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your date is always in that format, you can use a more general regular expression to replace the date:

```
my $string = 'startDate="2014-06-10"';
$string =~ s/startDate="\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}"/startDate=""/g;
```

and since `startDate=""` stays the same you really just need to replace the date itself:

```
my $string = 'startDate="2014-06-10"';
$string =~ s/\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}//g;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming perl >5.10:

```
s/startDate="\K[^"]{10}//g;
```

Replaces 10 characters which aren't `"` following `startDate="`. Using `\K` means you don't need to replace the bit you wanted to retain:

> \K , which causes the regex engine to "keep" everything it had matched
>   prior to the \K and not include it in $&